# Checkstyle: enforce ){ to be on the same line with method/constructor arguments

Tags: checkstyle

Is there any way to reject these coding styles with Checkstyle? (i.e. having `) {` on a new line should be forbidden for methods, constructors, etc.):

```
    void doSomething1(String argument1, Integer argument2
    ) {

    }
    void doSomething2(
          String argument1,
          Integer argument2
    ) {

    }
    void doSomething3(String argument1,
                     Integer argument2
    ) {

    }
```

Allowing this one:

```
    void doSomething1(String argument1, Integer argument2) {
        
    }
```

Or this:

```
    void doSomething2(String argument1,
                     Integer argument2) {

    }
```